# Update the setTitle for a ListField

Tags: blackberry

Hi developers I am working on a app where I need to set title for a  listField which contains 100 listItems. For each 20 items I need to change the title at run time. My class is extending MainScreen and I can able to set title for only one time only. While scrolling the items in it I am not able to update the title with new one.Each 20 elements are parsing values coming from xml file. How can I implement it.

Comment: It is unclear what is going on in your code. Are you calling setTitle() for several times and it did not update the title? Or you are looking for an approach on when/where to call setTitle() it order to fit your business logic?

Comment: Hi Arhimed,I have  a listField contains 100 listItems.When I scroll them, for each 20 items I need to update the title with new one.Where I can use the setTitle() so that I can update it with new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looks like I got your trouble - you don't know how to detect whether user has scrolled to 21st (41st, 61st, etc.) list item.

I think it is possible to track the currently visible list items from the `ListFieldCallback.drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics graphics, int index, int y, int width)` method. Note that `index` is "Row index to display". So in theory you should be able to call `MainScreen.setTitle(String title)` from the `drawListRow()` if `index` == 21 (41, 61, etc.).

Comment: Thanks Arhimed now it is working fine ..but when I scrolled items for some seconds it is complaining that "Device Error (DE427)" and the message "message queue full", then app get freezed. What is the reason for it. I am using Storm 9530 simulator.

Comment: As I got it from this post - http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Simulator-quot-device-Error-DE427-quot/m-p/557190 - this is only simulator issue (versus a real device).